# TFS build returning an error for the copy command

Tags: tfs

I have recently been charged with getting CI going using TFS and in testing a build definition I recieve the error:-

```
        C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (3717): The command "copy "C:\Builds\1\Project-Access\ReleaseDefinition\Sources\Project-Access\Access.MVC\Widgets\Access.Intuition.Widgets.Performance\C:\Builds\1\Project-Access\ReleaseDefinition\Binaries\Access.Intuition.Widgets.Performance.*" "C:\Builds\1\Project-Access\ReleaseDefinition\Sources\Project-Access\Access.MVC\Access.Intuition.Web\bin\"" exited with code 1.
```

Below is the code and I was wonder if there is something whrong with the syntax that is causing the foldername error above.

-->
  
    copy "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)$(TargetName).*" "$(SolutionDir)Access.Intuition.Web\bin\"

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ProjectDir and the TargetName have both a hardcoded drive in the values probably

C:\Builds\1\Project-Access\ReleaseDefinition\Sources\Project-Access\Access.MVC\Widgets\Access.Intuition.Widgets.Performance\C:\Builds\1\Project-Access\ReleaseDefinition\Binaries\Access.Intuition.Widgets.Performance

As I can see right now, use the command.

copy "$(TargetName).*" "$(SolutionDir)Access.Intuition.Web\bin\"

You can also use the  task to see the values of the variables during build.